# QGIS 2.8.1 print composer won't export all OpenCycleMap base layer tiles

Tags: qgis, tiles, print-composer, basemap

My set-up is Linux Mint 17.1, 32- bit system, QGIS 2.8.1-Wien.

I have a map with few layers including OpenCycleMap as a basemap.  In Print Composer the extent of the map is 32.5km x 22km square and the print page size is A1.

I am exporting from Print Composer to a large PNG image file of about 220Mb (container size) at a resolution of 200 DPI.

Everything exports to the image file fine, except OpenCycleMap. It does not appear to have enough time to download from the server.  There are therefore many missing background map tiles.

Comment: I though initially that it was something to do with viewing the page at 100% in Print composer. It's not. I'm not really sure what it is. All layers export to an image file correctly except the background map. If the Print Composer is left to settle for a while sometimes the export works - with all background map tiles exported - sometimes not. Does anyone know how to build a local OpenCycleMap server so I can test if the server tile speed serving is the issue?

Comment: please add to the question how did you actually added OpenCycleMap basemap to QGIS. There multiple ways to do it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here, just several statements

Comment: Could also be related to https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16267

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem solved by using "Quick Map Services" QGIS plugin instead of the "OpenLayers" one.